# ColdFusion round decimal value

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-11

```
<cfif (NOT IsNull(nt)) and (NOT IsNull(kt)) >
    <cfset ct= (nt * kt) / 100>
<cfelse>
    <cfset ct= 00.00 >
</cfif>
```

let nt = 77 and kt = 13.
ct will be 10.01.

I want to round the result to be 10.00.

I tried using round(ct), floor(ct).

```
`floor(62.72)` 
`floor(62.72)` 
`value="#Numberformat(ct,',9.99')#"`
```

Other scenario :
if ct = 12.31, result should be 12.30,
if ct = 22.48, result should be 22.48  (Not changed)

Comment: The answer has been posted, but some explanation as to what you are seeing would poss be helpful: https://blog.adamcameron.me/2016/01/floating-point-arithmetic-with-decimals.html. And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems. One needs to understand these things if one is doing programming.

Answer (score 2):

You want the Fix function

Fix(10.01) will result in 10

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
But It not what Im trying to do. 
I only what the result to round to nearest 0 if result is .01 and .02.
let say if value is 10.01, output should be 10.00, if value is 10.02, output should be 10.00, 
f value is 10.11, output should remain 10.11 and so on.
Fix (n) change all to .00  . So, it is not what im looking for.

Comment: I was going to recommend using the decimalRound UDF (https://cflib.org/udf/decimalRound), but it doesn't matter as the rounding is accurate whether up/down/even.  If you want to alter precision, you'll need to perform a post-computation comparison and then alter the value.